# `replace` versus plain `loop` for copying large arrays in SBCL

Tags: arrays, performance, optimization, common-lisp, sbcl

## Problem description

Let's say you want to copy large specialized arrays in SBCL. Naturally, you want it to be fast, memory efficient and you want the syntax to be nice.

Two ways of doing this would be:

```
(defparameter *arr1* (make-array 100000 :element-type 'double-float
                                        :initial-element 1d0))
(defparameter *arr2* (make-array 100000 :element-type 'double-float
                                        :initial-element 0d0))

;; First method
(replace arr2 arr1 :start1 20000 :end1 90000)
;; Second method
(loop for i from 20000 below 90000 do
  (setf (aref arr2 i) (aref arr1 i)))
```

At first sight, `replace` seems to be nicer because of its compact syntax but the benchmark results discourage me from using it all the time.

## Comparing the performance of `replace` versus `loop`

I suspect this is highly platform and compiler dependent. I used `SBCL 1.5.2` on `Linux x86_64 5.1.3_1` on a AMD Ryzen first generation CPU.

To perform the comparison, let's write some tests:

```
(defun spec-replace (arr1 arr2)
  (declare (type (simple-array double-float) arr1 arr2)
                 (optimize (speed 3)))
  (replace arr2 arr1 :start1 20000 :end1 90000))

(defun spec-loop (arr1 arr2)
  (declare (type (simple-array double-float) arr1 arr2)
                 (optimize (speed 3)))
  (loop for i from 20000 below 90000 do
    (setf (aref arr2 i) (aref arr1 i))))

(declaim (inline spec-loop spec-replace))

(let ((arr1 (make-array 100000 :element-type 'double-float
                               :initial-element 1d0))
      (arr2 (make-array 100000 :element-type 'double-float
                               :initial-element 0d0)))
  (time (spec-replace arr1 arr2))
  (time (spec-loop arr1 arr2)))
```

You have the choices of:

- Toggling the `(speed 3)` on each function.
- Toggling the `inline` declaration for each function.

The results seem to be that:

- `spec-loop` and `spec-replace` are tied in number of CPU cycles when optimized or unoptimized but both not inlined.
- `spec-loop` has a huge advantage when both functions are inlined. Between x3 or x4 the speed.
- The output of `disassemble` for the fully optimized `spec-loop` is quite a bit shorter than for `spec-replace`.

## Questions

1. Since the two methods are fairly simple and conceptually perform the same operation, why can't SBCL optimize them down to the exact same compiled instructions? Is there a reason other than the fact that it is not implemented in SBCL yet?
2. Would writing a macro with the `replace` syntax that expands to the `loop` method be useful?
3. I am guessing that the `loop` optimization comes at the cost of higher memory usage, since there is a difference between the default optimization and `(speed 3)`. Will I hit a point of diminishing return in large projects that make heavy use of this kind of operation?

Of course, the answer to all this is: test on a case by case basis. But can someone share some wisdom on this type of problem?

Comment: For the question 1: they do not perform exactly the same operation. For `replace`: “If sequence-1 and sequence-2 are the same object and the region being modified overlaps the region being copied from, then it is as if the entire source region were copied to another place and only then copied back into the target region.” (from the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_replac.htm#replace)), while the loop has a simple “assign an element at time” semantics.

Comment: `replace` undoubtedly has more features yes, including the one you mention of copying one region of a sequence onto another overlapping region. But in the very narrow case I describe above, I cannot see why SBCL cannot recognize that two different non-overlapping arrays are used. My question 1. being: is this possible at all for a Common Lisp compiler? I suspect that it is, but I don't know the first thing about compilers.

Comment: In CCL the replace is consistently slower than the loop.

Comment: How about inlining REPLACE?

Comment: Adding a `(declaim (inline replace))` does not seem to change the timings. I think it is already inlined automatically on the `(speed 3)` setting. I tried to search in the SBCL codebase to check this but did not find the definition for `replace`.

Answer (score 4):

Asking for source of REPLACE leads to different possible sources (Emacs + Slime, <kbd>M-.</kbd> (meta-dot)):

```
..../sbcl/src/code/seq.lisp
  (DEFUN REPLACE)
..../sbcl/src/compiler/seqtran.lisp
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (*)) SIMPLE-BASE-STRING &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE (SIMPLE-BASE-STRING (SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE (SIMPLE-VECTOR SIMPLE-VECTOR &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (COMPLEX DOUBLE-FLOAT) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (COMPLEX DOUBLE-FLOAT) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (COMPLEX SINGLE-FLOAT) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (COMPLEX SINGLE-FLOAT) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (SIGNED-BYTE 64) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (SIGNED-BYTE 64) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY FIXNUM (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY FIXNUM (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (SIGNED-BYTE 32) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (SIGNED-BYTE 32) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (SIGNED-BYTE 16) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (SIGNED-BYTE 16) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (SIGNED-BYTE 8) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (SIGNED-BYTE 8) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 64) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 64) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 63) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 63) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 62) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 62) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 32) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 32) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 31) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 31) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 16) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 16) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 15) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 15) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 7) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 7) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 4) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 4) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 2) (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 2) (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE (SIMPLE-BIT-VECTOR SIMPLE-BIT-VECTOR &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY DOUBLE-FLOAT (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY DOUBLE-FLOAT (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY SINGLE-FLOAT (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY SINGLE-FLOAT (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE ((SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (*)) (SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (*)) &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM REPLACE (SIMPLE-BASE-STRING SIMPLE-BASE-STRING &REST T) "optimize")
..../sbcl/src/compiler/knownfun.lisp
  (:DEFOPTIMIZER REPLACE SB-C:DERIVE-TYPE)
..../sbcl/src/compiler/fndb.lisp
  (DECLAIM REPLACE SB-C:DEFKNOWN)
```

The one we are interested in is the optimizer for SIMPLE-ARRAY of DOUBLE-FLOAT. Following the cross-reference leads to a somewhat suspicious line in `sbcl/src/compiler/seqtran.lisp`, a call to a macrolet `(define-replace-transforms)` (at line 999) that eventually relies on `!make-replace-transform`, in the same file.

The function is preceded by a big comment about how the loop is implemented.

The code branches out to different implementations, but there is one directly visible in the function that could be useful to test, as another benchmark, based on the function's comment; it goes as follows:

```
    (do ((i start1 (1+ i))
         (j start2 (1+ j))
         (end (+ start1 replace-len)))
        ((>= i end))
      (declare (optimize (insert-array-bounds-checks 0)))
      (setf (aref seq1 i) (aref seq2 j)))
```

For example, here is what doing the `do` loop explictly gives:

```
(deftype double-array () '(simple-array double-float (*)))

(declaim (type double-array *arr1* *arr2*))

(defparameter *arr1*
  (make-array 100000 :element-type 'double-float
                     :initial-element 1d0))

(defparameter *arr2*
  (make-array 100000 :element-type 'double-float
                     :initial-element 0d0))

(defun spec-from-source (&aux (arr1 *arr1*) (arr2 *arr2*))
  (declare (type double-array arr1 arr2)
           (optimize (speed 3) (debug 0) (safety 0)))
  (let ((start1 20000) (start2 0) (replace-len #.(- 90000 20000)))
    (do ((i start1 (1+ i))
         (j start2 (1+ j))
         (end (+ start1 replace-len)))
        ((>= i end))
      (declare (optimize (sb-c::insert-array-bounds-checks 0)))
      (setf (aref arr1 i) (aref arr2 j)))))
```

The tests are as follows:

#### replace

```
(time
 (dotimes (i 2000)
   (spec-replace)))

Evaluation took:
  0.201 seconds of real time
  0.200000 seconds of total run time (0.200000 user, 0.000000 system)
  99.50% CPU
  481,862,984 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

#### loop

```
(time
 (dotimes (i 2000)
   (spec-loop)))

Evaluation took:
  0.130 seconds of real time
  0.132000 seconds of total run time (0.132000 user, 0.000000 system)
  101.54% CPU
  312,538,278 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

#### as expected by reading the source code

```
(time
 (dotimes (i 2000)
   (spec-from-source)))

Evaluation took:
  0.097 seconds of real time
  0.096000 seconds of total run time (0.096000 user, 0.000000 system)
  98.97% CPU
  231,766,644 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

I doesn't look like the code you wrote expands as that one above, based on how the performance are different. The disassembly from `SPEC-REPLACE` shows

```
; C2B:       E828AAB6FD       CALL #x2036D658                 ; #<FDEFN SB-KERNEL:UB64-BASH-COPY>
```

It calls one of the so-called *bash-copy* functions, the first case in the COND in `!make-replace-transform`. A little bit of investigation gives `!define-byte-bashers` and `frob-bash-transform` as interesting functions to study. It seems like the function referenced as `unary-bash-name` is doing a lot of work to find how to write specialized code for different cases.

1. I am not familiar with that code, but at least the source is available; it however requires a lot more time to understand how it works, and how the compiler choose one path or another when optimizing things.
2. This might be a good question to ask at SBCL developers (sbcl-help mailing list).
3. Note that the DO approach is the one being the fastest here, if you need to optimize that case a lot. It seems like the *"byte-basher"* family of functions could be even more specialized, but I am not sure about that. If you ever find out more about this, please consider adding an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your investigation. I did not have the knowledge to understand this from reading the source. But now I know where to look if I want to understand the reason why replace doesn't expand to the same thing as the loop or do methods.